# Does anyone know of a Firebug equivilant for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, firebug

The question says it all. Inter Explorer's lack of standard compliance has struck, and driven me to the brink of madness. Does anyone know of a Firebug equivalent for IE8?

Comment: Tools -> Developer tools (or F12)?

Comment: What's wrong with the bundled dev tools that come with IE8?

Comment: @Martin Nothing for just inspecting--eeeverything when editing. That being said, that's pretty much the tool to use.

Comment: In my experience it wasnt IE8 I needed to debug as much as IE6.  Now a firebug plugin for IE6, that would be awesome! (Or decommissioning IE6, but lets face it thats not going to happen for a while!)

Comment: It doesn't have the same functionality; it's unintuitive and very difficult to find the right place to look. It would be nice if there was an "inspect element" option under right-click!

Comment: I can't visually see margins either!

Comment: I've had difficulty setting Firebug Lite up with IE 9, using all of the methods mentioned on their website. Is anyone else having such a problem? We may need a new answer to this question, or a pointer to good instructions for setting up Firebug Lite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

> Firebug is an extension for Firefox,
>   but what happens when you need to test
>   your pages in Internet Explorer,
>   Opera, and Safari?
>
> The solution is Firebug Lite, a
>   JavaScript file you can insert into
>   your pages to simulate some Firebug
>   features in browsers that are not
>   named "Firefox".
>
> Firebug Lite creates the variable
>   "firebug" and doesn't affect or
>   interfere with HTML elements that
>   aren't created by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Download the internet explorer  developer toolbar

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

You may be surprised, but Visual Studio is a great tool for debugging Javascript (or JScript, as MS calls it). Just attach an IE process, view the running scripts and set breakpoints wherever you like. As for DOM inspection, it can't help you there. But it's how I debug in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx) for IE8

cheers

Comment: Thanks Andriyev, but I find using them more of a pain than help! Maybe I'm ignorant of this feature, or too used to Firebug, but I don't find them intuitive.